# How can I give the match a higher score if another term is matched in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement something like this:

```js
{
    should : [
        { term : { title : 'A' } },
        { term : { title : { value : 'B', boost : `100 if the term "A" matches, otherwise 1` } } }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First `term` query should be used in field with type `keyword` for `text` field is better to use the `match` here you can find the solution using `term`:

```
{ "query":{
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "title": {
              "value": "A",
              "boost": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": {
              "value": "B",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

by using `match` (recommended):

```
{ "query":{
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "A",
              "boost": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "B",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```